# Test data structure with formik and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-testing-library

I am begginer in react-testing-library and I am looking for a way to comparise objects in react-testing-library and Formik. I would like to:

- Submit Form
- and test if the structure is compatible

```
it("will check the matchers and pass", () => {
  const object = {
    timeInTheWeek: [
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
    ],
    selected: true
  }

  expect(object).toMatchSnapshot({
    selected: expect.any(Boolean),
    timeInTheWeek: expect.any(Array),
  })
})
```

I've made a snapshot of this object, and how I should compare these two objects after submiting form (one from snapshot and one from submit form data)? Should I render additional textarea and match it with `.toHaveTextContent()`? I have no idea how it should be handled properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not supposed to do snapshot matching with react-testing-library. Also, can you create a minimum code example for your Formik form? I presume that `selected` property corresponds to checkbox. Not sure about `timeInTheWeek`.

Comment: So how I should resolve this problem to test submition of form and test data structure? Have any ideas?

Comment: Read my updated comment. Thanks.

Comment: @BranislavLazic Selected is checkbox and timeInTheWeek is FieldArray. Later I adjust Formik code.

Answer (score 0):

Name your test, and perform tests from a users perspective

```
it("should have selected something and display time slots in a week", () => {
  const object = {
    timeInTheWeek: [
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
      "10:00",
    ],
    selected: true
  }

  // Render your form
  const { getByText } = render(<Form />);
  // Wait for form to get updates
  await wait();

  // Check whether the checkbox is true
  expect(getByText("Text in your checkbox").checked).toEqual(object.selected);
  // Check the value of the first field. You can e.g. generate `datatest-id's` using field indicies and prefix them with e.g. "time-in-the-week-id-".
  expect(getByTestId("time-in-the-week-id-0")).toBe(object.timeInTheWeek[0]);
});
```